# Keras input_shape error

Tags: python, keras

I keep receiving this error:

```
Error when checking target: expected dense_256 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (10,)
```

I have check my X_train variable and I get a shape of (576,10).  So, I have 576 samples, each with 10 features (all of which have been scaled already).

I now try this:

```
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Dense(units = 5, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation = 'relu', input_shape=(10,)))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 5, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 5, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 5, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation = 'relu'))
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mse', 'mae', 'mape'])
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs=100)
```

Which is when I get the input_shape error referenced above.

So, my question is, when defining input_shape, how do I set this correctly?

Comment: What is the shape of y_train ?

Comment: Thank you Ufuk.  Your question made me realize that I had accidentally screwed up the train_test_split, which created wrong dimensions for y_train.  you have solved my issues.

Comment: You are welcome :)